# How to split out the path received from os.path.dirname()

Tags: python

Lets say I have a python file saved inside the directory

```
E:\Data\App
```

So when I did `print os.path.dirname(str(sys.argv[0]))`, it showed me the above path. Now lets say I want to create a new file inside `E:\Data\Conf\`, so how to cut out App and use Conf and save the file inside `E:\Data\Conf`

I cannot directly use the complete path because `E:\Data\` will not be common and will vary.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just call `dirname` on it again to go one more level up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from os.path import dirname, join

file_dir = dirname(the_file)
parent_dir = dirname(file_dir)
conf_dir = join(parent_dir, 'Conf')
```

`dirname` always gets the directory containing whatever path you pass it, so calling it on your file will get you the app directory; calling it again on the app directory will get you the parent of that. You can then use `os.path.join` to attach `"Conf"` or whatever other directory you want.

Another way is using `os.path.abspath` along with `os.pardir` to go up any number of levels:

```
import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

conf_dir = abspath(join(dirname(the_file), os.pardir, "Conf"))
                                         # ^ You can add more of these to go up the heirarchy
```

The inner `join` call with `os.pardir` will construct a path like `"E:\Data\App\..\Conf"`, and `abspath` will resolve it into `"E:\Data\Conf"`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Can you please  explain it

Comment: @SAndrew I added a bit of explanation, is there anything still not clear?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One last doubt, if I have a directory structure like `E:/data1/data2/data3/data4` and from data4 I want to move directly to data1. So instead of doing `os.path.dirname()` again and again, is there any other way of jumping to data1 directly.?

Comment: @SAndrew if you know how many levels you want to go, just use the second method I showed and add more `os.pardir`.

Comment: You can split the string and slice then join according to your need.                                                                                         
        `path = 'E:/data1/data2/data3/data4'`                                                                         
         `path = path.split()`     then     `'/'.join(path.split('/')[:2])`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
path = 'E:\Data\conf' # Or however you will assign this
dir_path = '\\'.join(path.split('\\')[:-1]) + '\\' # 'E:\Data\'
```

This basically splits the string of the path by `\`, then rebuilds the string with all but the last path in the tree.